# Can I remove @JvmField annotation when converted java adapter file to kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-listview, android-viewholder

Hi in my list view adapter which was in java, I converted it to Kotlin and field in my viewholder class now has `@jvmField` annotaion

is that correct to have this, what should it be replaced with

this is my java viewholder class

```
public static class ViewHolder {
    @BindView(R.id.ticket_no)
    @Nullable
    public TextView ticketNo;
}
```

when converted to kotlin file

```
   @JvmField
   @BindView(R.id.ticket_no)
   var ticketNo: TextView? = null
```

can the annotation @JvmField field be removed if so what should it be replaced with

please suggest

thanks in advance
R

Answer (score 3):

`@JvmField` indicates weather the kotlin compiler should generate `getters/setters` for this property or not. If its set then it will not generate `getters/setters` for this property . You can omit it in this case .

To verify this you can go - `Double shift -> show byte code` and de-compile it. You can see the difference with `@JvmField` the field is exposed as public.

```
public static final class ViewHolder {
  @BindView
  @JvmField
  @Nullable
  public TextView ticketNo;
 }
```

and without it field is private and expose via `getters/setters`.

```
public static final class ViewHolder {
  @BindView
  @Nullable
  private TextView ticketNo;

  @Nullable
  public final TextView getTicketNo() {
     return this.ticketNo;
  }

  public final void setTicketNo(@Nullable TextView var1) {
     this.ticketNo = var1;
  }
  }
```